# How to connect Azure Storage Account to Static WebApp using Managed Identities?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-account

I was following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-app-access-storage-javascript?tabs=azure-portal

But I ended up with the following error:
[image: error]

Are there any way to solve this issue or another way of connecting Static WebApp to Storage Account?